# Displaying images in Popup of ArcGIS Flexviewer

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-server

I have created a sample flex application using the ArcGIS Flex viewer and trying to access some images from web(wiki).

I have successfully configured the pop-up XML files such that it displays the images. However when I click on the feature, it is not showing the image.

I was thinking if this could be because of the fact that these images are larger to include within the pop-up window.

I have tried the following workarounds of using different tags in the Pop-up config xml.

## workaround:1

```
<description><![CDATA[<a href="{LINK_NEW}"><img src="{LINK_NEW}"/>{LINK_NEW}</a>.<br>a. ]]>
</description>
```

## workaround:2

```
<medias>
  <media chartfields="" type="image" imagesource="{LINK_NEW}" imagelink="{LINK_NEW}" /> 
  </medias>
```

The second seems to get me near to the resolution but not able to see the images in the pop-up window.

The question here is, I wanted to know a way to resize the original image with the help of xml tags and also if possible I wanted to increase the size of the pop-up window as well as to reduce the size of image that fits the pop-up window.

My configuration file is like the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<configuration>
    <title>{NAME}</title>        
    <medias>
    <media chartfields="" type="image" imagesource="{LINK_NEW}" imagelink="{LINK_NEW}" />
    </medias>
    <fields>
            <field name="NAME" alias="NAME" visible="true"/>
                <field name="LOCID" alias="LOCID" visible="true"/>
                <field name="STATE" alias="STATE" visible="true"/>
                <field name="ACAIS" alias="ACAIS" visible="true"/>
        <field name="LINK_NEW" alias="LINK_NEW" visible="false"/>
    </fields>
    <showattachments>true</showattachments>  
</configuration>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that we cannot access larger images in the pop-up window, which might be an enhancement that needs to be done with the pop-up configuration.

And also figured out that accessing larger images is possible through FLEX API by using image control in the pop-up configuration. Below are the few links that might be helpful.

Image Control:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=controls_16.html

PopUpRendererSkin:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/apiref/com/esri/ags/skins/PopUpRendererSkin.html